# Using timestamp in file loaded with SQL Loader

Tags: linux, oracle, sql-loader

I need to load XXXX named dat file everyday in Oracle database. But thing is, I need to read simila file with timestamp like: XXXX20191120.dat
Is it possible to create such a configuration in .ctl that INFILE '/blaa/blaa/blaa/XXXXX20191120.dat' part is possible to different in each day ? If so, please example.

If this has to be done with separate shell script, please example.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a different filename each time, don't put it in the ctl file, use the command line parameter DATA e.g.

```
    data=/bla/bla/xxxxx20191121.dat
```

look at the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-4F0321D7-B141-453B-B5D2-2553230CDFBF.htm#SUTIL1023), I gave the 12.1 ref as you did not specify which version you're using.